Seminorm of sum of two elements
I have a fundamental question about semi-normed spaces:
Let $(V, |\cdot|)$ be a semi-normed space and let $x,y \in V$ such that $|x| > 0 $ and $|y| = 0$. Can something be said about the seminorm of $x+y$? I think that we should have $|x+y| > 0$ but I did not succeed in proving it. I thought about taking the quotient $V/K$, where $K$ is the preimage of $0$ of the seminorm. I think this quotient is a normed space and I tried to look at the class of $x+y$, which should be the same as $[x]$ since $y \in K$, but I didn't get much further. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The triangle inequality yields $0<|x|=|(x+y)-y|\le |x+y|+|y| =|x+y|$.

@Gerd oh my bad, that was easy. Thank you for your comment. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Ok, I can do that.

From the properties of a semi-norm (triangle inequality and absolute homogeneity) we have
$$
0<|x|=|(x+y)-y| \le |x+y| + |-y| = |x+y| + |y|=|x+y|.
$$
